# Optimizing monte carlo simulation in R

Tags: r, optimization

The following example takes projected team sales data, and distributes it amongst the team members according to their projected sales% (expressed as a cumulative distribution by each team). There are 250 team members from 5 teams, and projected sales from 1000 quarters. The team members' sales% changes for each iteration. Everything in the top half of the code is not optimized, but it's handed to me to run the simulation so I can't change it (i.e. don't focus on optimizing it).

The current example runs on my computer in roughly 120 seconds. I'm looking to get it cut down to under 30 seconds, but I'm not really sure the best approach. I've read about multi-threading but I'm unfamiliar with it. I'm also sure there's a better way to vectorize my problem instead of nesting 3 for-loops, but I'm not exactly sure where to start. Any help getting started in the right direction would be much appreciated. I have a 2021 M1 Max 64gb memory.

```
library(dplyr)

### Assign number of simulated quarters, Team Member IDs, and respective sales teams ###
num_quarters <- 1000
salesMembers <- 1:250
salesTeams <- LETTERS[1:5]
salesMemberTeamDF <- data.frame(salesMember = salesMembers, salesTeam = sample(salesTeams, length(salesMembers), replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Make sample cumulative distribution for sales team (not optimized, ignore)
sampleCumDist <- c()
for(i in 1:num_quarters){
  for(t in salesTeams){
    currSalesTeamNum <- salesMemberTeamDF %>% filter(salesTeam == t)
    sampleCumDist <- c(sampleCumDist, sort(runif(nrow(currSalesTeamNum)-1)), 1)
  }
} 

# Get dataframes of projected total sales by quarter, and team member distribution by quarter
salesMembersDF <- data.frame(salesMember = rep(salesMembers, num_quarters), Quarter = rep(1:num_quarters, each = length(salesMembers)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  left_join(salesMemberTeamDF, by = c('salesMember')) %>% arrange(Quarter, salesTeam) %>% 
  mutate(cumDist = sampleCumDist) %>% 
  mutate(totalSales = 0)
salesDF <- data.frame(Quarter = rep(1:num_quarters, each = length(salesTeams)), salesTeam = salesTeams, sales = round(runif(num_quarters*length(salesTeams), 1, 4), 0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
### Note: everything above this line I cannot change - it's a part of the setup/processes handed to me ###


## Benchmark timestamps
numSalesFilterTime <- 0
salesMemDFFilterTime <- 0
selectTeamMemberTime <- 0
addSalesToDFTime <- 0
salesSimStart_time <- proc.time()

# For each quarter, get the total sales data and distribute amongst team members based on their sales distribution
for(q in 1:num_quarters){
  for(t in salesTeams){
  
    # Get the current quarter's projected total sales
    numSalesFilterTimeFix <- proc.time()
    numSales <- salesDF %>% filter(Quarter == q & salesTeam == t) %>% pull(sales)
    numSalesFilterTime <- numSalesFilterTime + (proc.time() - numSalesFilterTimeFix)[3]
    
    # Get the current quarter's projected sales distribution
    salesMemDFFilterTimeFix <- proc.time()
    salesMembersDF_CurrRun <- salesMembersDF %>% filter(Quarter == q & salesTeam == t)
    salesMemDFFilterTime <- salesMemDFFilterTime + (proc.time() - salesMemDFFilterTimeFix)[3]
    
    # For each sale, determine which team member gets credit
    for(sale in 1:numSales){
      
      # Based on a random variable and the cumulative distribution, assign the sale to respective team member.
      # Get random variable
      saleRV <- runif(1)
      
      # Based on that random variable and cumulative distribution, determine who gets credit for sale
      selectTeamMemberTimeFix <- proc.time()
      currSalesMember <- salesMembersDF_CurrRun$salesMember[min(which(saleRV < salesMembersDF_CurrRun$cumDist))]
      selectTeamMemberTime <- selectTeamMemberTime + (proc.time() - selectTeamMemberTimeFix)[3]
      
      # Add current sale to main DF
      addSalesToDFTimeFix <- proc.time()
      salesMembersDF$totalSales[salesMembersDF$salesMember == currSalesMember & salesMembersDF$Quarter == q] <- salesMembersDF$totalSales[salesMembersDF$salesMember == currSalesMember  & salesMembersDF$Quarter == q] + 1
      addSalesToDFTime <- addSalesToDFTime + (proc.time() - addSalesToDFTimeFix)[3]
    }
  }
}

{
totalSalesSimTime <- (proc.time() - salesSimStart_time)[3]
if((proc.time() - salesSimStart_time)[3] < 60){
  cat("\n--- It took ", round(((proc.time() - salesSimStart_time)[3]), 2), " seconds to distribute ProjSales ---\n\n", sep = "")
} else {
  cat("\n--- It took ", round(((proc.time() - salesSimStart_time)[3])/60, 2), " minutes to distribute ProjSales ---\n\n", sep = "")
}
cat('Total time filtering Sales:           ', format(round(numSalesFilterTime, 2), nsmall = 2), ' seconds (', format(round(numSalesFilterTime/totalSalesSimTime*100, 1), nsmall = 1), '% of total time)\n', sep = '')
cat('Total time getting cumDist:           ', format(round(salesMemDFFilterTime, 2), nsmall = 2), ' seconds (', format(round(salesMemDFFilterTime/totalSalesSimTime*100, 1), nsmall = 1), '% of total time)\n', sep = '')
cat('Total time selecting teamMember:      ', format(round(selectTeamMemberTime, 2), nsmall = 2), ' seconds (', format(round(selectTeamMemberTime/totalSalesSimTime*100, 1), nsmall = 1), '% of total time)\n', sep = '')
cat('Total time adding sale:               ', format(round(addSalesToDFTime, 2), nsmall = 2), ' seconds (', format(round(addSalesToDFTime/totalSalesSimTime*100, 1), nsmall = 1), '% of total time)\n', sep = '')
}

finalSalesData <- salesMembersDF %>% 
  group_by(salesMember) %>% 
  summarise(totalSales = mean(totalSales))
```

Comment: In your first for loop you sort the runif realizations for each interation but then concatenate the sorted vectors.  Which does not seem to make much sense.  What is your objective there?

Comment: @SteveM As noted I'm just trying to setup the dummy-example in the way the data gets handed to me, it's not optimized. I'm just setting up the cumulative distributions for each member/team, it should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

A fully vectorized base R approach using `findInterval` takes a fraction of a second:

```
system.time(
  salesMembersDF$totalSales <- tabulate(
    findInterval(
      runif(sum(salesDF$sales)) + rep.int(1:nrow(salesDF), salesDF$sales),
      salesMembersDF$cumDist + cumsum(!duplicated(salesMembersDF[,2:3]))
    ) + 1L, nrow(salesMembersDF)
  )
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.29    0.02    0.31
```

The idea is to take the uniform samples all at once and then offset them by their corresponding row numbers in `salesDF`. For example, say there are 3 projected sales in row 1, then `runif(sum(salesDF$sales)) + rep.int(1:nrow(salesDF), salesDF$sales)` will return 3 values between 1 and 2. Since both `data.frame`s are ordered by `Quarter` and `salesTeam`, we then use `findInterval` to match each random value to `salesMembersDF$cumDist` after it is also offset by the cumulative number of unique {`Quarter`, `salesTeam`} combinations in `salesMembersDF`. Note that since `cumDist` is the upper end of the interval, `findInterval` will return 1 less than the desired index.

### Bonus

It is straightforward to perform multiple replications in sublinear time:

```
system.time({
  N <- 1e3 # number of replications

  totalSales <- Rfast::colTabulate(
    matrix(
      findInterval(
        runif(N*sum(salesDF$sales)) + rep.int(1:nrow(salesDF), N*salesDF$sales),
        salesMembersDF$cumDist + cumsum(!duplicated(salesMembersDF[,2:3]))
      ) + 1L, ncol = N, byrow = TRUE
    ), nrow(salesMembersDF)
  )
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.29    0.46    1.75
```

Each column of `totalSales` is a replication:

```
dim(totalSales)
#> [1] 250000   1000
```